# React Router navigation between routes with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been learning React Router by constructing a simple blog application, but I got stuck right away with a simple functionality of Previous Post and Next Post buttons. My first Router looked like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Posts} />
  <Route path="posts/:id" component={PostView} />
</Route>
```

Posts:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchPosts } = this.props.actions;
    const url = window.Routes.posts_path({ format: 'json' });
    fetchPosts(url);
  }

  render() {
    const { posts, isFetching } = this.props.posts;
    const opacity = isFetching ? '0' : '1';
    return (
      <section className="posts-list post-view" style={{ opacity }}>
        {posts.map(post =>
            <Post
              key={post.id}
              id={post.id}
              title={post.truncated_title}
              content={post.truncated_content}
              commentsCount={post.comments.length}
              date={post.created_at}
            />
          )
        }
      </section>
    );
  }
```

PostView:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchSinglePost } = this.props.actions;
    const id = this.props.params.id;
    const url = window.Routes.post_path(id, { format: 'json' });
    fetchSinglePost(url);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  render() {

      ***
      <footer className="post-footer">
        <div className="prv">
          <Link to={window.Routes.post_path(`${id - 1}`)}>
            &#8592; Previous post
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="nxt">
          <Link to={window.Routes.post_path(`${id + 1}`)}>
            Next post &#8594;
          </Link>
        </div>
      </footer>
      ***
    );
  }
```

But the routing doesn't work as expected: there's a `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action logged, URL is changed, re-render is initiated, but no content change takes place. I've tried to make the `PostView` a nested route, like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="posts" component={Posts}>
    <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostView} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

And then in the `Posts` component:

```
  <section className="posts-list post-view" style={{ opacity }}>
    {this.props.children || 
      posts.map(post =>
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          id={post.id}
          title={post.truncated_title}
          content={post.truncated_content}
          commentsCount={post.comments.length}
          date={post.created_at}
        />
      )
    }
  </section>
```

Reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import postsReducer from './postsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  posts: postsReducer
});
```

Initialisation:

```
const store = configureStore();
const routes = configureRoutes(store);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(
  browserHistory,
  store
);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history} children={routes} />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
}, false);
```

The general data flow still works, i.e. `Posts` render results of `posts.map()` on the `/posts` route and render `PostView` on the `/posts/:id` route but navigating between `/posts/:id` from inside of the `PostView` still doesn't work. I've read tutorial on the GitHub, but it didn't really help and I'm out of ideas. I would appreciate pointers how I can solve this. I'm also using `react-router-redux` if it's related.

Comment: Could you include your store configuration and setup? React-router-redux hooks into the store (see https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#api) in particular way for synchronization to work correctly

Comment: @markthethomas, you mean part where I apply `syncHistoryWithStore` hook? I can include it, but it's basically copypasted from documentation and seems to work properly. BTW I've also tried to achieve navigation manually by using `push` provided by `react-redux-router`, alas to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, or at least where you include the reducer. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#routerreducer has to be included to work and sync :)

Comment: @markthethomas, updated.

Comment: Well, you're missing a comma between componentDidMount and render. Not sure if that was just a copy-paste error.